# ErrorException Trying to get property 'title' of non-object (View: C:\DK\Practice\Laravel\example-app\resources\views\product.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-7

I am getting below shown error in Laravel website. The goal over here is to display the product. I have also shared the image of the error on this issue log. Kindly check and let me know where the issue is as I am not able to figure out.

I am running the laravel project locally. Any suggestion or help from the Laravel community is welcomed. Please help so that I can proceed further.

> ErrorException
> Trying to get property 'title' of non-object (View: C:\DK\Practice\Laravel\example-app\resources\views\product.blade.php)

> Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError
> C:\DK\Practice\Laravel\example-app\resources\views/product.blade.php:9

```
    <x-base-layout>
    
    
    
        <div class="flex m-4">
    
            <div class="w-1/2 rounded shadow overflow-hidden">
    
                {{-- <img class="object-cover w-full" src="{{asset($product->image_url)}}"/> --}}
    
            </div>
    
                <div class="w-1/2 rounded bg-white ml-2 p-4 shadow relative">
    
                    <div class="font-semibold">{{$product->title}}</div>
    
                    <div class="text-sm text-gray-500">{{$product->short_desc}}</div>
    
                    <div class="text-xs text-gray-500 mt-2">{{$product->long_desc}}</div>
    
    
                    {{-- Seller info --}}
    
                    <div class="mt-4">
    
                        <div class="text-xs font-semibold text-gray">Sold by</div>
    
                        <div class="text-sm text-gray-500">{{$product->user->name}}</div>
    
                    </div>
```

1 - product.blade.php

```
<x-base-layout>


    <div class="flex m-4">
        <div class="w-1/2 rounded shadow overflow-hidden">
            {{-- <img class="object-cover w-full" src="{{asset($product->image_url)}}"/> --}}
        </div>
            <div class="w-1/2 rounded bg-white ml-2 p-4 shadow relative">
                <div class="font-semibold">{{$product->title}}</div>
                <div class="text-sm text-gray-500">{{$product->short_desc}}</div>
                <div class="text-xs text-gray-500 mt-2">{{$product->long_desc}}</div>

                {{-- Seller info --}}
                <div class="mt-4">
                    <div class="text-xs font-semibold text-gray">Sold by</div>
                    <div class="text-sm text-gray-500">{{$product->user->name}}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="mt-2">
                    <div class="text-xs font-semibold text-gray">Phone number</div>
                    @auth
                        <div class="text-sm text-gray-500">{{$product->user->phone}}</div>
                    @else
                    <div class="text-sm text-gray-500">********** <a href="/login" class="text-xs text-blue-500">Login to view</a></div>
                    @endauth

                </div>
                <div class="mt-2">
                    <div class="text-xs font-semibold text-gray">Email address</div>
                    @auth
                        <div class="text-sm text-gray-500">{{$product->user->email}}</div>
                    @else
                    <div class="text-sm text-gray-500">********** <a href="/login" class="text-xs text-blue-500">Login to view</a></div>
                    @endauth
                </div>

                {{-- Product price --}}
                <div class="absolute bottom-0 right-0 m-6 rounded-full px-4 py-2 bg-green-500">
                    <div class="text-white font-fold text-sm">Rs. {{$product->price}}/-</div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>

</x-base-layout>
```

2 - ProductsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    //fetch all products
    public function index() {
        $products=Product::all();
        return view('products')->with('products',$products);
    }

    //Fetch a product by id
    public function show($id){
        $product=Product::find($id);
        return view('product')->with('product',$product);
        dd($product);
    }
```

3 - Route - web.php

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/



Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth'])->name('dashboard');

Route::get('/',[ProductsController::class,'index']

);

Route::get('/product/{id}',[ProductsController::class,'show']);
```

Error screenshot:

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: The error is telling you that your variable `$product` is not an object (which you likely expect it to be). Try debugging the return values from your database quieries in your functions and see what it is you're actually getting back.

Comment: use foreach loop. foreach($product as $res){$title = $res->title;}

Answer (score 1):

I think, you have a little prob in your `show()` method. What happen if the find method return a null? You will exactly get what you are getting, trying to access a property on null object.

Change you code as bellow, and then you'll get a 404 Not found.

```
 //Fetch a product by id
    public function show($id){
        $product=Product::findOrFail($id);
        return view('product')->with('product',$product);
        dd($product);  // This will never be executed.
    }
```